# Cognitive Services Exception in Xamarin App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

Hi I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services and it's giving me an exception for some unknown reason. This is the way I declared FaceServiceRestClient:

```
var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("MY_KEY");
```

when I run above code it throws an exception by saying "Your Subscription key is invalid". I checked 3-4 times Key is correct, I also regenerated key and used it still exception is there.

Now, I added second parameter, thats URL so not my declaration is as follows:

```
var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient("MY_KEY", "https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0" );
```

For above statement I get an exception as "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=MY_KEY/detect"

This is how I am calling detect method (If you want to see)

```
Com.Microsoft.Projectoxford.Face.Contract.Face[] result = faceServiceClient.Detect(@params[0], true, false, null);
```

I do not understand exactly where to look at or which declaration is correct. & BTW this is Xamarin application and I used Xamarin.Microsoft.Cognitive.Face package. If you want to anything else in my code please Comment I will share code snippet.
Can anyone please help?
Thank you

Comment: Yes. I am using Free Subscription.. Does that make diff.?

Comment: For sure, this is my endPoint https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=MY_KEY/detect"

That package wraps the Android/Java API and that API is different then the other platforms. In the case of `FaceServiceRestClient`, the Azure Face Endpoint is the first param, and your Face API key is the second.

Note: They did not even name the parameters in the binding library so you will see param names such as `p0` `p1` throughout the C# API :-( I ended up using `Rekognition` to work around the throughput limitations of Cognitive services, but that is a different story)

I stripped down a camera/photo tagger that I wrote to get you started.

#### Example:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient(faceEndpoint, faceAPIKey);
    using (var imageFileStream = camera.SingleImageStream)
    {
        var faceAttributes = new FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType[] { FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.Gender, FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.Age, FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.Smile, FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.Glasses, FaceServiceClientFaceAttributeType.FacialHair };
        var faces = faceServiceClient.Detect(imageFileStream, true, false, faceAttributes);
        foreach (var face in faces)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"{face.FaceRectangle.Left}:{face.FaceRectangle.Top}:{face.FaceRectangle.Width}:{face.FaceRectangle.Height}");
            DrawFaceRect(face.FaceRectangle);
            TagPhoto(face.FaceAttributes);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess that worked! But, I am getting another exception saying "image size is too Big.." And I checked in properties, the size of image is 819 Kbs only.

Comment: @Pro-n-apps What is the width/height of the image in pixels? What is the encoding format of the image?

Comment: its Solved buddy.. Thanks. You are legend!! :)

Comment: Now I can go ahead with identify and GetPerson methods. Hope those might have same syntax as standard MS.ProjectOxford.Face package. BTW, do you find any documentation for  Xamarin.Microsoft.Cognitive.Face, if you can you please link it here.?? Thank You

Comment: @Pro-n-apps Since this library is a C# Binding library on top of the Android/Java library, I use the Java API docs. You have to handle the C# normalization yourself, Camel-casing props/methods, setXXX/getXXX becomes C# properties, etc... https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android

Comment: Yeah, I can see what you are trying to say because you declared FaceServiceRestClient like var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient(faceEndpoint, faceAPIKey); but the way we do, is var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceRestClient(faceAPIKey, faceEndpoint); need to study those things..

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, In the same package I am using   var results = faceServiceClient.Identity(personGroupId, faceIds, 5); It returns me list of Candidates but not the PersonId in it. Can you please suggest me work around to get PersonId